# ngbRadioButtonGroup angular checked

Tags: angular

I have made a form and I would like the radioButton automatically tick according to the previous answers
So I have a payload that I communicate to each of my components arrive at the last one I have all the necessary information but I try to automatically validate the buttons it does not work

I have in my animalPayload.gender (Male if the user select male female ...)

My code:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic" formControlName="gender">
              <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
                <input ngbButton type="radio" value="Undefined" [checked]="animalPayload.gender == 'Undefined' ? true : false"> <i class="fas fa-genderless"></i>
              </label>
              <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
                <input ngbButton type="radio" value="Male" [checked]="animalPayload.gender == 'Male' ? true : false"> <i class="fas fa-mars"></i>
              </label>
              <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
                <input ngbButton type="radio" value="Female" [checked]="animalPayload.gender == 'Female' ? true : false"> <i class="fas fa-venus"></i>
              </label>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you've missed a point in the [ngbRadio documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/buttons/api#NgbRadio) where it does not mention any [checked] attribute binding.

I'd rather suggest to try out your input elements like:

```
<input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="animalPayload.gender == 'Undefined' ? true : false">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to change the [checked] to [value] but that doesn't change anything ... it still doesn't work I checked that my payload was not empty or contained bad information but this is not the case I do not understand